# Matching regex for Google Analytics campaigns

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I am trying to use regex to match campaign names in a segment in Google Analytics that contain the word Partner.

I have 5 campaigns that all start with the word Partner. I have tried using ^ to match all campaigns that begin with Partner. However, Google Analytics seems to be pulling the data from the first campaign that starts with Partner and then ignores the remaining 4. My campaign names also use pipes in the naming convention so this could also be causing an issue.

Campaign names I need to group as a segment are below:

- Partner|GSP|Generic
- Partner|GDN|Generic
- Partner|GDN|Remarketing
- Partner|GDN|Node|DSA
- Partner|GDN|Node|LTA

thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is `^partner` but it sounds like you've already tried that.

I've never seen pipes inside campaign names before, but you can use \ to de-regex them, so a more manual approach would be to search for each one of those, using a regex such as:

`^Partner\|GSP\|Generic$`

Turning each of the terms into a regex like this, and connecting them with pipes, gives:

`^Partner\|GSP\|Generic$|^Partner\|GDN\|Generic$|^Partner\|GDN\|Remarketing$|^Partner\|GDN\|Node\|DSA$|^Partner\|GDN\|Node\|LTA$`